# escape hidden character that is causing JSON validation to fail

Tags: javascript

I have a hidden character that is causing JSON parsing to fail. What is the best way to escape a string properly just that hidden characters like these done crash my json?

Here is the code, the invisible character is between the n and the s in "brains" until you remove that invisible character JSON.parse() will fail... question is, how to strip the invisible character?

```
var mystring='{"invis":"their brains process differently"}';
console.log("cool" + mystring);
console.log(JSON.parse(mystring));
```

Note I found that in the above code actually removed the invisible character, but it is here on pastie, if you want to copy and paste to see the issue:
[See the code on pastie](http://pastie.org/1485072)

Comment: What is a hidden character?  Do you know your string's encoding?

Comment: it was in the DB as UTF-8 to begin with

Comment: the page it came from was UTF-8 as well

Answer (score 2):

Somehow a cancel character (0x18) got into your string. You can simply replace it out with a regular expression.

```
var mystring='{"invis":"their brains process differently"}';
mystring = mystring.replace( /\x18/g, "" );
console.log("cool" + mystring);
console.log(JSON.parse(mystring));
```

Comment: I'm wondering if there is more of a generic fix that would not allow any funky invisible chars to break JSON.parse().  Is there some way to cast mystring to something that is a little more friendly?

Comment: @Anthony Webb: you could change the regular expression to "/[^\w\s]/g" which will remove any non white space, non alpha-numeric character. You'll need to expand it the regular express to leave in the special characters such as :, {, }, (, ), etc.

Comment: Am I the only one who finds it odd that JSON.parse() cannot properly parse it in the first place?

Comment: Is this "cancel" character (0x18) the only one that will break JSON.parse()?

Comment: If I had to guess, and that's all it is, I would say only keyboard characters minus line return and tab are valid. With a little experimenting I'm sure you could figure out which ones are and are not valid on your own.

Answer (score 2):

I found another JSON parser that doesnt crash with these hidden characters, it is located here:

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js